# How to pass data from one html page to another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that has several links that link to the same page, but depending on the link the user clicks I need to pass different info to that other page. I know how to do this in PHP through the URL and using $_GET[] but I am unsure how to do it using only javascript/jquery and html. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a hashbang (`#!`) to store data, but that's a little sketchy.

Comment: javascript is stateless between page changes, choices are cookie, localStorage or url params. Javascript can set or get any of those

Comment: localStorage is persistent as Hell.  Consider using sessionStorage if one doesn't like the query string solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a query string to the link, just as you would to use $_GET with PHP, but retrieve the query string on the target page using JavaScript, as explained here: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Edit: I've looked some more at the page to which I linked.  There's a lot of very general code there, but if you use an = sign and only one parameter, you can split off the parameter with a JavaScript split:

```
<a href="target.html?from=A">Came from A</a>
```

target.html's 'location.search' will contain "?from=A" and a simple split will do it.

Comment: Also, note that this approach does not require JavaScript on the sending page, only on the target page.  (If you have JavaScript on the sending page anyway, well, that's a horse of a different color.)